# Deleting mysql db syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Im trying to tidy up my local dbs which are left over duplicates and dev dbs from past projects.

To do it im viewing in Sequel pro, then im deleting them using the command  `DROP DATABASE testdatabase;` that works fine.

But some of my dbs have names like `lorem-blog-db` (with dashes) when i try to run `DROP DATABASE lorem-blog-db;` it gives me back an error near 'lorem-blog-db'.

Any idea how to resolve this ? i guess its to do with the dashes.

Comment: `lorem-blog-db` is not valid. use grave accent to enclose the database name

Comment: did you try using backticks? `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, you can use backticks to escape names.  Like so:

```
DROP DATABASE `my-least-favorite-db`
```